# SVN not prompting for username and password

Tags: linux, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable password in both commit and checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000007/enable-password-in-both-commit-and-checkout)

I installed subversion (version 1.6.11) on our RedHat Enterprise 6.3 Linux server. I then created a repository using the command:

```
svnadmin create /home2/svnrepo
```

I then added the following entries to **/home2/svnrepo/conf/svnserve.conf** file:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
realm = My SVN Repository
```

I added an svn user by adding following entry to **/home2/svnrepo/conf/passwd** file:

```
joe = joepw
```

I imported a project into SVN using the command:

```
svn import /home/joe/projects/myproject file:///home2/svnrepo/myproject
```

I then started the SVN Serve Daemon:

```
svnserve -d
```

When I try to checkout the project using the following command from a different machine, **I am not being prompted for a password**. However, the project is being checked out fine. Why is that so?

```
svn co svn://54.245.0.1/home2/svnrepo/myproject
```

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I added the entries at the end of the svnserve.conf file. I moved those entries to the [general] section. And that solved the issue!